# CBR-600 F3 1998 Ignition Barrel Replacement

Tags: ignition-key, bolts, fastener

my lads CBR-600F3 1998 ignition barrel has got so badly corroded we can't use the existing key. Locksmith has had a look at it and can't do anything. So I am looking to replace the barrel. I've seen replacements which show the complete assembly (see right half of picture)[image: BARREL_PICTURE]. To remove the barrel its looks like I'd need to remove the bolts (red circled) in the picture - on the bike these look like rivets, there is no bolt head / screw I can remove.

I've also seen some instructions suggesting I remove the only three (circled blue) screws.
I'm something of an amateur so before I have at the three screws, can anyone confirm this will work?

Here is a better picture of the underneath. I have removed the 3 screws holding parts 2-3 on your diagram. Where the two bolts are shown, that is where I see the two "rivets". I did try taping with a mallet, in case those rivets were just driven home, didn't budge.

[image: Picture of the underside]

There are no other bolts that I can see holding the assembly to the bike. I can't believe that the whole yoke would need replacing but it's looking that way!

Answer (score 0):

No, don't remove the rivets.  Those hold the assembly together.  The screws mount it in place.

Here is the parts diagram from:

[Parts Fiche](https://www.ronayers.com/oemparts/a/hon/506c19b5f870023420a2eb94/handlebar)

[image: CBR600 Parts Diagram]

It shows the ignition key switch mounted using the two bolts.  (Callout 15)

Comment: I believe the task is to replace the entire assembly not open the existing one up and fix it.

Comment: Yes, a closer look tells me you're right. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: ok so removing the three screws (blue circled) will release all that you see n the right half of the picture? Thanks for reply btw :)

Comment: I've now removed the 3 screws (blue) and that allowed the rear of the ignition barrel to come away. The key lock and associated assembley is still on the bike. Looking more closely there does not appear to be any way that the assembly can be removed without drilling out the rivets.

Comment: See the diagram that I updated my answer with.  This is an older bike, it make take some persuasion to come loose.  Try tapping with a mallet.